# Get initial form value with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a php generated form like this

```
<form onsubmit="formSubmit(this)" method="post"> 
    Product Name <input name="prID" type=" text" value="poney" readonly></input>
    Platform Name<input name="platform" type="text" value="Jambon"></input>
    <input  type="submit" value="OK">   
    <input type="reset" value="Cancel">
</form>
```

Ok so now if you click on Cancel, your form is reset and the value of input are reset to the initial value. What I want to do is get the form intial value in my formSubmit(this) function.

if a I do something like

```
formSubmit(form){
    alert(form[0].value+form[1].value); 
}
```

the output will be something like "*poney what ever you type*"
what I want is

```
formSubmit(form){
    alert(form[0].value+" old value: "form[1].initialvalue+" new value: "+form[1].value); 
 }
```

which is supposed to give output like this "*poney old value: jambon new value: whatever*"

Do you know a way of getting those information, as it seems that they are stored somewhere?

Comment: You can save initial values of the fields when the form loads, and then use it on form submission

Comment: I never understand why everybody remove the "hello" and "best regard" in the message, it's nice to have someone asking politely things sometime. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to just save it on document load (unless it's being populated by AJAX or some other post-load event; then you'd have to store the initial state there).

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    var $form = $('form'),
        formOriginalValue;

    // store initial state on page load
    formOriginalValue = $form.serializeArray();

    // catch the submit handler and compare
    $form.submit(function(e){
      // given 'element1' is a text box:
      //
      // original value: formOriginalValue['element1']
      //      new value: $('[name="element1"]', this).val();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks that's what I feared. in fact the form is loaded by ajax call to a php function. so it's not that easy. But now I know at least where I can find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution may be to use [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp), jQuery has a [built-in data() function](http://api.jquery.com/data/) in order to manage these data.